# How to reset System.currentTimeMillis() every seconds?

Tags: android

i want to make an app that can set a variable within 2 seconds

```
 final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
                Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
                        int decis = (int) ((millis % 1000)/10);

                        TimerBox.setText(String.format("Time: %d.%02d", seconds, decis));
                        Tx.setText(""+counting);
                        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
                        if(seconds == 2){
                            counting = 1;
                            seconds = 0;
                            decis = 0;
                        }
                    }
                };
```

this is not my code, im curently new in android studio

Answer (score -1):

```
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(time>=2000)
                {
                    time=0;
                    //do things here
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

In this way you can know when two seconds are passed